# How to copy the postgresql's xlog files safely

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I mean how to safely copy xlog files when postgresql is running? Any reply will be appreciated.

Comment: Why? What do you intend to achieve from doing this? The WAL archives are completely useless without a corresponding base backup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best (and recommended) way to do it is to configure the database server to copy them via the [archive_command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-ARCHIVE-COMMAND) configuration variable. See also the chapter [Setting up WAL Archiving](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-ARCHIVING-WAL).

If you are hell bent on copying them manually then another way might be to look at the contents of the archive_status subdirectory. When you see a file in this directory with the suffix .ready it means that the corresponding WAL file is completed and should be safe to copy. However I don't think this would happen unless WAL archiving was turned on in the first place - if it is not turned on then postgres will just delete the WAL files soon after they are written (which will not give you much chance to copy them!)

Comment: I'd go further, and say that the *only* safe way to copy WAL archives is with an `archive_command` except in the specific case of doing an initial database backup with `pg_start_backup()` and `pg_stop_backup()`, where a filesystem level copy is safe *if* you follow the rules in the documentation. These days it's much safer to use `pg_basebackup` for that, so you should never have to copy WAL manually. Ever.